# React/Redux I have two components I want to pass the data in one into state using handleClick to the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component that produces pairs of names from an array, inside this I need to select the name, keep it highlighted and then when I choose add it to a new array in local state using a submit in a different component. I would like to be able to select or deselect the piece of data as well.

The reducer and actions are setup, I need local methods or a function to do this, I understand some Lifting State might be needed but can't work it out.

This is the component in which I am using a button and onClick to select the piece of data:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../App.scss";
import Button from "../Button/Button";

class Matches extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: false,
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
 handleClick() {

  this.setState({ selected: !this.state.selected }); 
}

  render() {
    const { pairs } = this.props;
    let { selected } = this.state;
    return (
      <ul>
        {pairs.map((item, index) => (
          <div className="pairs container__roster__list" key={index}>
            {item.map((names, index) => (
              <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="player" >
                {names}
              </button>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default Matches;
```

Here is the component in which I need to pass that data to in order to submit that data to local state to store it and then pass it to global state:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../App.scss";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Button from "../Button/Button";
import Matches from "../Matches";

class Tournament extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      winners: [],
      round: 0,
    };
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    const { winners } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      winners:
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    const { winners, round } = this.state;
    this.setState({ winners: winners, round: round + 1 });
    this.props.handleNextRound(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    const { winners } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container__tournament">
          <h1 className="title__App">PING PONG</h1>

          <section className="container__roster round-one">
            <Matches />
            <Button
              buttonClass="button"
              label="Next Round"
              handleClick={this.handleSubmit}
              disabled={winners.length === 4 ? false : true}
            />
          </section>

          <section className="container__roster semi-final">
            <h2 className="round__title"></h2>
            <Button
              buttonClass="button"
              label="Next Round"
              handleClick={this.handleSubmit}
            />
          </section>

          <section className="container__roster final"></section>

          <Link to={"/"} className="nav-link nav__tournament">
            <Button buttonClass="button " label="Settings" />
          </Link>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Tournament;
```